# How can I make my switch less code? working with characters in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a function which returns a fancy character, normally I should type all cases for all alphabet with capital and non capital characters, can I make this less code?

```
func alphabet(character: String) -> String {
    
    switch character {
    case "A":
        return ""
    case "B":
        return ""
    default:
        return character
    }

}
```

PS: I am thinking about Unicode characters, but no idea how make it works less code.

---

For example this is the characters I like to use, but I do not know the name of it, it is found-able in macOS.

[image]

---

**update: working code**

```
   import SwiftUI
    
    
    struct ContentView: View {
    
        @State private var stringOfText: String = String()
    
        var body: some View {
    
            Text(stringOfText)
    
            TextField("Enter your String here...", text: $stringOfText)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                .padding()
    
            Button("Build the New String") {
    
                stringOfText = buildNewStringFunction(string: stringOfText)
     
            }
            .font(Font.body.weight(Font.Weight.bold))
            .padding(.bottom)
            
            
            
            Button("Build the New String UpperCase") {
    
                stringOfText = buildNewStringFunction(string: stringOfText.uppercased())
     
            }
            .font(Font.body.weight(Font.Weight.bold))
            .padding(.bottom)
            
            
            
            Button("Build the New String Lowercased") {
    
                stringOfText = buildNewStringFunction(string: stringOfText.lowercased())
    
            }
            .font(Font.body.weight(Font.Weight.bold))
            .padding(.bottom)
            
            
            
            Button("Build the New String Capitalized") {
    
                stringOfText = buildNewStringFunction(string: stringOfText.capitalized)
    
            }
            .font(Font.body.weight(Font.Weight.bold))
            .padding(.bottom)
    
        }
        
    }
```

---

```
    let upperCaseCharacters: Dictionary<Character, Character> = [ "A": "", "B": "", "C": "", "D": "", "E": "",
                                                                  "F": "", "G": "", "H": "", "I": "", "J": "",
                                                                  "K": "", "L": "", "M": "", "N": "", "O": "",
                                                                  "P": "", "Q": "", "R": "", "S": "", "T": "",
                                                                  "U": "", "V": "", "W": "", "X": "", "Y": "", "Z": "" ]
    
    
    
    let lowerCaseCharacters: Dictionary<Character, Character> = [ "a": "", "b": "", "c": "", "d": "", "e": "",
                                                                  "f": "", "g": "", "h": "", "i": "", "j": "",
                                                                  "k": "", "l": "", "m": "", "n": "", "o": "",
                                                                  "p": "", "q": "", "r": "", "s": "", "t": "",
                                                                  "u": "", "v": "", "w": "", "x": "", "y": "", "z": "" ]
    
    
    
    let numberCharacters: Dictionary<Character, Character> = [ "0": "", "1": "", "2": "", "3": "", "4": "",
                                                               "5": "", "6": "", "7": "", "8": "", "9": "" ]
```

---

```
    func alphabet(character: Character) -> Character {
        
        
        switch character {
        case character where character.isUppercase:
    
            if let value: Character = upperCaseCharacters[character] {
                
                return value
                
            }
            else {
                
                return character
                
            }
    
        case character where character.isLowercase:
    
            if let value: Character = lowerCaseCharacters[character] {
                
                return value
                
            }
            else {
                
                return character
                
            }
    
        case character where character.isNumber:
    
            if let value: Character = numberCharacters[character] {
                
                return value
                
            }
            else {
                
                return character
                
            }
    
        default:
            
            return character
            
        }
     
    }
```

---

```
    func buildNewStringFunction(string: String) -> String {
        
        var newCharacters: String = String()
        
        string.forEach { item in
            
            newCharacters.append(alphabet(character: item))
            
        }
        
        print(newCharacters)
        
        let pasteboard = UIPasteboard.general
        pasteboard.string = newCharacters
        
        return newCharacters
        
    }
```

Comment: You could define a dictionary `const charMap = ["A": "", "B": "", ...]` and then do `return charMap[character] ?? character`

Comment: Yeah good idea!

Comment: Is it a character or a string?

Comment: It should just take single character, my func need refactoring

Comment: @swiftPunk it is still unclear what you want to return in case the input is a capital b `"B"`

Comment: @LeoDabus: why unclear? look like this: "B": "", "b": "" and so on,

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to get all related characters based on a single character

Comment: You are right, I should just limit my func to your given Ranges, and that would be ok, I mean if the Character was not in those range then return the Character, as you answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Character ClosedRange:

```
func alphabet(character: Character) -> Character {
    switch character {
    case "A"..."Z":
        print("A...Z")
        return character
    case "a"..."z":
        print("a...z")
        return character
    case "0"..."9":
        print("0...9")
        return character
    default:
        return character
    }
}
```

If you would like to check if the character is uppercase or lowercase:

```
func alphabet(character: Character) -> Character {
    switch character {
    case let x where x.isUppercase:
        print("isUppercase")
        return character
    case let x where x.isLowercase:
        print("isLowercase")
        return character
    default:
        return character
    }
}
```

Comment: That is what I needed, and then I should use a dic for my fancy character, right?

Comment: Can you be more specific about which character would be returned and the actual input?

Comment: I just updated your last func, I omitted x and add number case as well, is it ok?

Comment: @swiftPunk the only thing I can think of is to loop all possible unicode values and check the character unicode name if it contains the "B" character by itself (between boundaries)

Comment: I can post a possible approach but it is returning 35 instead of 45 related characters I am not sure why

Comment: No way Leo! please I never wished bother you at all, you already helped me, I solved the issue with your answer, let me update in up

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
extension String {
    func toBold() -> String {
        if !("A"..."Z").contains(self) { return self }
        let diff : UInt32 = 119808 - 65 // heh heh
        let u = self.unicodeScalars[self.startIndex].value + diff
        return String(Unicode.Scalar(u)!)
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
let x = "A".toBold()
print(x) //
```

That's just for capital letters, but you can see how to extend it to whatever your real use case is.