# Building Unicode scalar String in Swift

Tags: swift

How can I make **"\u{3A9}"** String with coding? here what I tried, but did not worked!

```
let omegaHexadecimal: String = "3A9"
let omega = "\u{" + omegaHexadecimal + "}"
```

---

Or:

```
let omegaHexadecimal: String = "3A9"
let omega = "\u{\(omegaHexadecimal)}"
```

---

**Update:**

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {

    private var decodingUnicodeCharacters: String { applyingTransform(.init("Hex-Any"), reverse: false) ?? "" }

    func stringToUniCodeHexConvertor(upTo lenght: Int = 4, using character: Character = "0") -> String {
        
        return ("\\u" + repeatElement(character, count: Swift.max(0,lenght-count)) + self).decodingUnicodeCharacters
    }

}
```

---

```
let omegaHexadecimal: String = "3A9"
let omega = omegaHexadecimal.stringToUniCodeHexConvertor()
print(omega)   // "Ω"
```

Comment: @matt: please read question next time before downvoting or commenting, my question is about to build the String that carry "\u{3A9}"

Comment: No! you did understand Wrong! As you can read and i explained building the **omega** And I just asked for help to building **omega** and I do not think that I must tell how I am going to use it! It is up to me how I am going to use

Comment: If the goal is to start with a string consisting of an omega, you just write `let omega = "Ω"`. So surely you do not mean _that_ eh. And both your example _do_ start with the string `"3A9"`, you surely cannot deny that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pad your string up to 4 hexa digits (2 bytes UInt16), add `\u` prefix `\uXXXX` and use a string transform to convert your unicode hexa value to the corresponding character:

```
extension StringProtocol where Self: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    func paddingToLeft(upTo lenght: Int = 4, using character: Character = "0") -> Self {
        repeatElement(character, count: Swift.max(0,lenght-count)) + self
    }
    var decodingUnicodeCharacters: String { applyingTransform(.init("Hex-Any"), reverse: false) ?? "" }
}
```

---

```
let omegaHexadecimal: String = "3A9"
let omega = "\\u" + omegaHexadecimal.paddingToLeft()  //  "\\u03A9"

omega.decodingUnicodeCharacters   // "Ω"
```

Comment: thanks to your knowledge and UNDERSTANDING the question, I am happy some could understand the question.

Comment: I just made some refactor on your code, can you look it that please? thank you

Comment: Note that the decoding property would decode all occurrences of \uXXXX in the string

Answer (score 0):

Why so complicated? Work with numbers directly:

```
let omega = UnicodeScalar(0x3A9)!
print(String(omega)) // Ω
```

Comment: I already showed the OP this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/66414284/341994 — one of those situations of not reading the answer one is given...

Comment: my question is about to build the String that carry "\u{3A9}" not printing! or using UnicodeScalar!

Comment: @matt: please read the question and compare with that Link!  before commenting, thank you.